# Extract multiple thumbnails in a batch with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a text file of frame numbers.  Is there a way using ffmpeg to extract a batch load of thumbnails from a video file using the text file all at once.

The code below extracts a single frame( frame 100 in this case) from a video file

```
ffmpeg -i in_video.avi -vf "select=gte(n\,100)" -vframes 1 out_img.png
```

Comment: You mean generate thumbnails for all the frames?

Comment: Yes, generate thumbnails from a list of frame numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to print the logfile you wanted in the last question, you'll have to run ffmpeg within a script - batch or shell, depending on OS e.g.

```
 while read textfile
 do
    ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n\,$textfile)'" -vframes 1 frame-$textfile.png
 done < logfile.txt
```

I'm not proficient in bash, so verify this syntax before execution.